# Ajax - Firefox not working

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

ajax chrome also works. But **firefox** is not working. I did not understand the reason. Sometimes I have this problem. Firefox also needs to be written differently. Help please.

```
$(function () {
            //[id$ = txtAra]
            $("[id$=txtAra]").autocomplete({
                source: function (request, response) {
                    $.ajax({

                        url: "/AramaScript.aspx/Search",
                        data: "{ 'prefix': '" + request.term + "'}",
                        dataType: "json",
                        type: "POST",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        success: function (data) {
                            response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                                return {
                                    label: item,
                                    val: item
                                }
                            }))
                        },
                        error: function (response) {
                            alert(response.responseText);
                        },
                        failure: function (response) {
                            alert(response.responseText);
                        }
                    });
                },
                select: function (e, i) {
                    $("#btnAra").click();
                },
                minLength: 1
            });
        });
```

Comment: By not working what do you mean? Failed API request? Code exception? What does the response object say in the error callback? What is the Network panel showing you?

Comment: @DominicTobias there is no return. It does not give an error message. It's just not trading. But chrome is no problem.

Comment: And what does it show in the network tab of Firefox development tools?

Comment: Tested your code. It works in FireFox.

Comment: Sorry. Other scripts had async. I have not seen it. It is the reason for not working. I solved the problem. I removed the **async = "async"** feature and it fixes the problem. Thanks for the answers.